# Jquery everything correct but not executing

Tags: jquery

What's wrong with the following jquery code? Why is it not working?
I am trying to count the number of columns in a table and set the width of this div with id "eDiv" but its not working

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    reset();

    function reset() {
        w = $("#eDiv tr:first td").length * 200;
        $('.container1').width(2000);
        alert('i');
    }
});
```

Comment: *"but its not working"* means what exactly? What happens and what do you expect to happen? You are setting the width of the element with class `container1`, not ID `eDiv`.

Comment: Your code "works fine": http://jsfiddle.net/pSfrS/

Comment: May be you want to use `$('.container1').width(w);` ?

Answer (score 1):

It is because your html ids or classes may not be defined. Confirm that they do exist.

Maybe you wanted to use

```
$('#eDiv').width(w);
```

OR

```
$('.container1').width(w);
```

OR

```
$('#eDiv').width(2000);
```

**EDIT:**
It is **NOT** because of declaring the function afterwards, as you can verify in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gopi1410/qhYp9/). *(pointed out by @Felix Kling)*